# JQuery: Calculation & Variable is not Displaying When Checkbox Checked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Still learning JQuery.  Still new to JQuery in fact.  Trying to code is:

When the an items checkbox is checked, it calculates the service fee times years.  then add the license fee to it.  Finally it takes the total and times the quantity, which in then creates the item_cost.

If more than one item is checked, it will also calculate the item_cost and adds each checked item's cost, creating a total_item_cost.  And, it will add each checked item's training hours, creating a total_training_hours.

Once item is done calculating, it will then display the item name, years, quantity, training hours, and total cost of each item that is checked at the bottom in the table.  It will also display another table with total training hours and the the total cost of all items.

I have coded below but cannot seem to get the items to show in the table.

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //First obtaining indexes for each checkbox that is checked
    $('input[id^=item_add]').change(function(){

        // get checkbox index
        var index = $(this).attr('id').replace('item_add','');

        //hide tables until box is checked
        $('table[id^=add_item_here]').hide();
        $('table[id^=add_totals_here]').hide();

        //If checkbox is checked, show tables, calculate item cost, get variables, calculate total cost, & calculate total training hours
        $('input:checkbox').change(function(){ 

            //If check box is check do...
            if($(this).is(':checked')){

                // Show totals tables
                $('#add_item_here').show();
                $('#add_totals_here').show();

                // start at 0 for item_cost
                var item_cost = 0;
                var total_cost = 0;
                $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){

                    // Calculating item cost for just that one checkbox
                    item_cost+=parseInt($('#servicefee'+index).val());
                    item_cost*=parseInt($('#yrs'+index).val()); 
                    item_cost+=parseInt($('#licensefee'+index).val());
                    item_cost*=parseInt($('#qty'+index).val()); 

                    // Get hidden variables to use for calculation and tables.
                    var item = $('#item'+index).val();
                    var traininghrs = parseInt($('#traininghrs'+index).val());
                    var qty = parseInt($('#qty'+index).val());
                    var yrs = parseInt($('#yrs'+index).val());
                } else {

                    //if not checked keep tables hidden
                    $('#add_item_here').hide();
                    $('#add_totals_here').hide();                                           
                }

                // start at 0 for total_costs
                var total_cost = item_cost;
                //Add item_cost with other item_costs to calculate total_cost
                $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
                    total_cost+= item_cost;
                }

                // start at 0 for total training hours
                var total_training = 0;
                //Add trianing hours with other training hours to calculate total_training
                $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
                    total_training+=parseInt($('#traininghrs'+index).val());
                }
            });

                //Display each item that is checked into a table
                $('#add_item_here tr:last').append('<td>' + item +'</td><td>' + yrs +'</td><td>' + qty +'</td><td>' + traininghrs + '</td><td>'+ item_cost + '</td></tr><tr>');

                //Display totals into table row into a table
                $('#add_totals_here tr:last').append('<td colspan=3 ></td><td>' + total_training + '</td><td>'+ total_cost + '</td></tr><tr>');

        });                                         

        // Quantity change, if someone changes the quantity
        $('#qty'+index).change(function(){
            $('input:checkbox').trigger('change');
        });

        // Years change, if someone changes the years           
        $('#yrs'+index).change(function(){
            $('input:checkbox').trigger('change');
        });                                         
    }           
}
 </script>
```

Need to have each items and their details shown in a table and then need to thave a total table.  So far the table format to display looks like:

```
 <table  id="add_item_here" style="width:98%;">
     <tr><td></td></tr>                                     
 </table>
 <table  id="add_totals_here" style="width:98%;">
     <tr><td></td></tr>                                     
 </table>
```

As requested, below is the HTML Form itself.

```
 <form id="myForm" method="post" class="price-quote-form" action="#" >                          

<div class="tx-row" style="width:100%; float:left; clear:right;">
    <div class="tx-column tx-column-size-2-3" style="float:left; margin-top:-20px; ">                               
        <label>
            <strong>Jurisdiction / Organization:</strong> <span style="font-size:10px; color:#ff0000;">(required)</span><br />
            <input style= "width:90%; height:35px; font-size:18px; border: 1px #396ba5 solid;" type="text" name="jurisdiction" required>
        </label> 
    </div>                                          
    <div class="tx-column tx-column-size-1-3" style="float:left; margin-top:-20px; ">                               
        <label>
            <strong style="font-size:14px;">State:</strong> <span style="font-size:10px; color:#ff0000;">(required)</span><br />
                <select style= "width:90%; height:35px; font-size:18px; border: 1px #396ba5 solid;"  id="state" name="state" required>
                    <option  value=""  >Select State</option>
                    <option value="IlIaNd"  >Iowa</option>
                    <option  value="IlIaNd" >Illinois</option>
                    <option  value="Minnesota" >Minnesota</option>
                    <option  value="Missouri" >Missouri</option>
                    <option  value="Nebraska" >Nebraska</option>
                    <option  value="IlIaNd" >North Dakota</option>
                    <option  value="SouthDakota" >South Dakota</option>                                                     
                </select>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>  
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#state").change(function(){
            $(this).on('change', function() {
                if(this.value =="IlIaNd"){
                    $(".box").not(".IlIaNd").hide();
                    $(".IlIaNd").show();
                }else if(this.value =="Minnesota"){
                    $(".box").not(".Minnesota").hide();
                    $(".Minnesota").show();
                }else if(this.value =="Missouri"){
                    $(".box").not(".Missouri").hide();
                    $(".Missouri").show();
                }else if(this.value =="Nebraska"){
                    $(".box").not(".Nebraska").hide();
                    $(".Nebraska").show();
                }else if(this.value =="SouthDakota"){
                    $(".box").not(".SouthDakota").hide();
                    $(".SouthDakota").show();
                }else{
                    $(".box").hide();
                }
            });
        }).change();
    });
</script>
<div style="width: 100%; float:left; clear:both; height:25px;" > </div>
<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc; width: 100%; float:left; clear:both;" > </div>
<div style="width: 100%; float:left; clear:both; height:25px;" > </div>
<div style="width: 100%; float:left; clear:both;" class="IlIaNd box">
    <?php IlIaNd_Price_Quote_Form() ?>
</div>
<div style="width: 100%; float:left; clear:both;" class="Minnesota box" >
    <p>test 2</p>
</div>
<div style="width: 100%; float:left; clear:both;" class="Missouri box">
    <p>test 3</p>
</div>
<div style="width: 100%; float:left; clear:both;" class="Nebraska box" >
    <p>test 4</p>
</div>
<div style="width: 100%; float:left; clear:both;" class="SouthDakota box">
    <p>test 5</p>
</div>

<center>
    <table  id="add_item_here" style="width:98%;">
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>Item</td><td>Years</td><td>Quantity</td><td>Training Hours</td><td>Total Item Cost</td></tr>    
        </tbody>
    </table>
</center>
<center>
    <table  id="add_totals_here" style="width:98%;">
        <tbody>
            <tr><td cospan=3></td><td>Total Cost</td></tr>  
        </tbody>
    </table>
</center>

 </form>
```

Here is the PHP Portion of the form, which I am grabbing the items and pricing from a database, and then create checkboxes with the item name, then I have the prices of both fees below it. And I also have a drop down on either how many years and / or quantity.

```
if (pg_num_rows($result) > 0){
    echo "<div class=\"tx-row\" style=\width:100%; clear:both; \" > <div style=\"width: 100%; float:left; clear:both; height:25px;\" > </div>";
    while ($row = pg_fetch_object($result)){
        $contractid = $row->id;
        $item = $row->descr;
        $license_fee = $row->license;
        $service_fee = $row->service;
        $hours = $row->training;
        echo "<div class=\"tx-column tx-column-size-1-3\" >
                <div id='item".$row->contractid."' style='width:100%;'>
                    <div style='width:10%; float:left;'>
                        <input style='height:25px; width:25px;' type='checkbox' id='item_add".$row->id."' name='item_add' value='add' /> 
                    </div>
                    <div style='width:90%; float:left;'>
                        <p style='width:115%;'><strong>$item</strong> <br /><span style='font-size:10px;'>Service Fee: &#36;$service_fee | License Fee: &#36;$license_fee</span></p>";
                        if ($contractid == "8" || $contractid == "10" ){
                            echo "<div style='width:100%; margin-top:-20px;'>
                                    <div style='width:50%; float:left;'>
                                        <span style='font-size:12px;'>Years: </span><select style='height:18px;' name='yrs' id='yrs".$row->id."'>
                                            <option value=\"1\">1</option>
                                            <option value=\"2\">2</option>
                                            <option value=\"3\">3</option>
                                            <option value=\"4\">4</option>
                                            <option value=\"5\">5</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style='width:50%; float:left;'>
                                        <span style='font-size:12px;'>Quantity: </span><select name='qty' id='qty".$row->id."' style='height:18px;'>
                                            <option value=\"1\">1</option>
                                            <option value=\"2\">2</option>
                                            <option value=\"3\">3</option>
                                            <option value=\"4\">4</option>
                                            <option value=\"5\">5</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type='hidden' name='item' id='item".$row->id."' value='".$row->descr."'>
                                    <input type='hidden' name='servicefee' id='servicefee".$row->id."' value='$service_fee'>
                                    <input type='hidden' name='licensefee' id='licensefee".$row->id."' value='$license_fee'>
                                    <input type='hidden' name='traininghrs' id='traininghrs".$row->id."' value='$hours'>
                                </div>
                                <div style='width:100%; height:25px; clear:both; float:left;'></div>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<div style='width:100%; margin-top:-20px;'>
                                        <span style='font-size:12px;'>Years: </span><select name='yrs' id='yrs".$row->id."' style='height:18px;'>
                                            <option value=\"1\">1</option>
                                            <option value=\"2\">2</option>
                                            <option value=\"3\">3</option>
                                            <option value=\"4\">4</option>
                                            <option value=\"5\">5</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <input type='hidden' name='Qty' id='qty".$row->id."' value='1' >
                                        <input type='hidden' name='item' id='item".$row->id."' value='".$row->descr."'>
                                        <input type='hidden' name='servicefee'  id='servicefee'  value='".$row->service."'>
                                        <input type='hidden' name='licensefee' id='licensefee".$row->id."' value='".$row->license."'>
                                        <input type='hidden' name='traininghrs' id='traininghrs".$row->id."' value='".$row->training."'>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style='width:100%; height:25px; clear:both; float:left;'></div>";
                        }
                        echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div> ";

            echo "</div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Hope adding the php and the html form helps anyone who can solve this out.

Here is the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/e9mmn55k/5/

Comment: When you append the html code generated you are adding something like `<td></td><td></td>...<td></td></tr><tr>`. That's not well formed HTML. It should be something like `<tr><td></td>...<td></td></tr>`.

Comment: I have updated them...         //Display each item that is checked into a table
                    $('#add_item_here > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>' + item +'</td><td>' + yrs +'</td><td>' + qty +'</td><td>' + traininghrs + '</td><td>'+ item_cost + '</td></tr><tr>');      

                    //Display totals into table row into a table
                    $('#add_totals_here > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td colspan=3 ></td><td>' + total_training + '</td><td>'+ total_cost + '</td></tr><tr>');        Still not working correctly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok...  Finally got the total hours and cost working on my price quote calculator...

```
 function CalculateTotals(){
        var total_cost = 0;
        var total_training = 0;
        $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
            var index = this.id.replace('item_chk','');
            var item_cost = 0;
            // Calculating item cost for just that one checkbox
            item_cost+=parseInt($('#servicefee'+index).val());
            item_cost*=parseInt($('#yrs'+index).val()); 
            item_cost+=parseInt($('#licensefee'+index).val());
            item_cost*=parseInt($('#qty'+index).val()); 
            var traininghrs = parseInt($('#traininghrs'+index).val());

            total_cost +=item_cost;
            total_training +=traininghrs;


        }); 

        if(total_cost > 0 || total_training > 0) {
            $('#add_totals_here tr:last').children().remove();
            $('#add_totals_here tr:last').after('<tr ><td colspan="3" style=\"width:66%;\">TOTALS:</td><td style=\"width:18%;\">' + total_training + '</td><td style=\"width:16%;\">$'+ total_cost + '</td></tr>');
            $('#add_item_here').show();
            $('#add_totals_here').show();
        }
        else{
            $('table[id^=add_item_here]').hide();
            $('table[id^=add_totals_here]').hide();
        }
```

To get the complete answer, feel free to email me...  But wanna shout out to mbadeveloper.  He helped me out a lot and helped me understand jquery a bit more.  Thanks mbadeveloper.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('table[id^=add_item_here]').hide();
  $('table[id^=add_totals_here]').hide();

        //First obtaining indexes for each checkbox that is checked
        $('input[name=item_add]').change(function(){
   var index = this.id.replace('item_chk','');
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
    AddNewItem(index);
   }
   else{
    RemoveItem(index);
   }
   CalculateTotals();                                         
        });

  function AddNewItem(index){
            // Get hidden variables to use for calculation and tables.
            var item = $('#item_chk'+index).parent().text().trim();
            var traininghrs = parseInt($('#traininghrs'+index).val());
            var qty = parseInt($('#qty'+index).val());
            var yrs = parseInt($('#yrs'+index).val());

            var item_cost = 0;
            // Calculating item cost for just that one checkbox
            item_cost+=parseInt($('#servicefee'+index).val());
            item_cost*=parseInt($('#yrs'+index).val()); 
            item_cost+=parseInt($('#licensefee'+index).val());
            item_cost*=parseInt($('#qty'+index).val()); 
            var traininghrs = parseInt($('#traininghrs'+index).val());          
            //Display each item that is checked into a table
            $('#add_item_here tr:last').after('<tr id="row_id'+index + '"><td>' + item +'</td><td>' + yrs +'</td><td>' + qty +'</td><td>' + traininghrs + '</td><td>'+ item_cost + '</td></tr>');  
  }
  
  function RemoveItem(index){
   $('table#add_item_here tr#row_id'+index).remove();
  }
  
  function CalculateTotals(){
            var total_cost = 0;
            var total_training = 0;
            $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
                var index = this.id.replace('item_chk','');
                var item_cost = 0;
                // Calculating item cost for just that one checkbox
                item_cost+=parseInt($('#servicefee'+index).val());
                item_cost*=parseInt($('#yrs'+index).val()); 
                item_cost+=parseInt($('#licensefee'+index).val());
                item_cost*=parseInt($('#qty'+index).val()); 
                var traininghrs = parseInt($('#traininghrs'+index).val());

                total_cost +=item_cost;
                total_training +=traininghrs;
            }); 

            if(total_cost > 0 || total_training > 0) {
    $('#add_totals_here tr:has(td)').remove();
                $('#add_totals_here tr:has(th)').after('<tr><td colspan="3">' + total_training + '</td><td>'+ total_cost + '</td></tr>');
                $('#add_item_here').show();
                $('#add_totals_here').show();
            }
            else{
                $('table[id^=add_item_here]').hide();
                $('table[id^=add_totals_here]').hide();
            }   
  }
  
  // Quantity change, if someone changes the quantity
  $('select[name=qty]').change(function(){
   var index = this.id.replace('qty','');
   if($("#item_chk"+index).is(':checked')){
    RemoveItem(index);
    AddNewItem(index);
    CalculateTotals();
   }
  });

  // Years change, if someone changes the years           
  $('select[name=yrs]').change(function(){
   var index = this.id.replace('yrs','');
   if($("#item_chk"+index).is(':checked')){
    RemoveItem(index);
    AddNewItem(index);
    CalculateTotals();
   }   
  });  
    })
```

```css
td {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="Calculate.js"></script>
 <body>
<div style="width: 100%; float:left; clear:both;" class="IlIaNd box">
 <div id="item11" style="width:50%;">
        <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
   <input style="height:25px; width:25px;" type="checkbox" id="item_chk11" name="item_add" value="add" /> Adance Search HTML
  </div>
        <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
            <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
    <span style="font-size:12px;">Years: </span><select style="height:18px;" name="yrs" id="yrs11">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
    <span style="font-size:12px;">Quantity: </span><select name="qty" id="qty11" style='height:18px;'>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" name="itemdescr" id="itemdescr11" value="Adance Search HTML">
   <input type="hidden" name="servicefee" id="servicefee11" value="1000">
   <input type="hidden" name="licensefee" id="licensefee11" value="3000">
   <input type="hidden" name="traininghrs" id="traininghrs11" value="8">
  </div>
  <div style="width:100%; height:25px; clear:both; float:left;"></div>
    </div>
 <div id="item12" style="width:50%;">
        <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
   <input style="height:25px; width:25px;" type="checkbox" id="item_chk12" name="item_add" value="add" /> Adance Search PHP
  </div>
        <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
            <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
    <span style="font-size:12px;">Years: </span><select style="height:18px;" name="yrs" id="yrs12">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
    <span style="font-size:12px;">Quantity: </span><select name="qty" id="qty12" style='height:18px;'>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" name="itemdescr" id="item_descr12" value="Adance Search PHP">
   <input type="hidden" name="servicefee" id="servicefee12" value="1500">
   <input type="hidden" name="licensefee" id="licensefee12" value="1000">
   <input type="hidden" name="traininghrs" id="traininghrs12" value="2">
  </div>
  <div style="width:100%; height:25px; clear:both; float:left;"></div>
    </div>
 <div id="item14" style="width:50%;">
        <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
   <input style="height:25px; width:25px;" type="checkbox" id="item_chk14" name="item_add" value="add" /> Adance Search WWW
  </div>
        <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
            <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
    <span style="font-size:12px;">Years: </span><select style="height:18px;" name="yrs" id="yrs14">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
    <span style="font-size:12px;">Quantity: </span><select name="qty" id="qty14" style='height:18px;'>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" name="itemdescr" id="item_descr14" value="Adance Search WWW">
   <input type="hidden" name="servicefee" id="servicefee14" value="0">
   <input type="hidden" name="licensefee" id="licensefee14" value="250">
   <input type="hidden" name="traininghrs" id="traininghrs14" value="0">
  </div>
  <div style="width:100%; height:25px; clear:both; float:left;"></div>
    </div>
 <div id="item15" style="width:50%;">
        <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
   <input style="height:25px; width:25px;" type="checkbox" id="item_chk15" name="item_add" value="add" /> Adance Search HTTP
  </div>
        <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
            <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
    <span style="font-size:12px;">Years: </span><select style="height:18px;" name="yrs" id="yrs15">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
    <span style="font-size:12px;">Quantity: </span><select name="qty" id="qty15" style='height:18px;'>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" name="itemdescr" id="item_descr15" value="Adance Search HTTP" >
      <input type="hidden" name="servicefee" id="servicefee15" value="1000">
   <input type="hidden" name="licensefee" id="licensefee15" value="0">
   <input type="hidden" name="traininghrs" id="traininghrs15" value="10">
  </div>
  <div style="width:100%; height:25px; clear:both; float:left;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<center>
 <table  id="add_item_here" style="width:98%;"  border="1">
  <tbody>
   <tr><th>Item</th><th>Years</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Training Hours</th><th>Total Item Cost</th></tr> 
  </tbody>
 </table>
</center>
<center>
 <table  id="add_totals_here" style="width:98%;" border="1">
  <tbody>
   <tr><th colspan="3">Training Hours</th><th>Total Cost</th></tr> 
  </tbody>
 </table>
</center>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ShadyNicNack please check the code and let me know if its working for you?

Comment: I can see the top and bottom border of a table, but still no item cost totals and total cost totals show inside them.

Comment: Somehow it is not either reading my calculation or not reading the display portion.

Comment: Can you add the full html or create a fiddle for it to check why is not display the calculation

Comment: I have added the HTML Form portion of the code and the PHP portion of the code which hooks up to the database and pulls pricing information.

Comment: @ShadyNicNack I change the code now you can see the total rows but its pending to update it when untick a checkbox or change the dropdownlist selected option

Comment: Thank you very much.   added the code and still not able to get the rows to show up...    Quick question....  How would you print variables in jquery.   I am so used to php and able to echo out anything.  JQuery is a bit different.

Comment: Here is the link to what I did so far and still working on it...   https://jsfiddle.net/e9mmn55k/6/

Comment: Ugggh!   Still not working.  Just doesn't seem to pull any information in.   Wondering it's the index portion not working.  Each item has a special index like there is index number 11 which 11 is on servicefee11, item11, licensefee11 and so on.  If that is the case then how am I suppose to distinguish which item checked item is which.

Comment: Another question... is there a way to check what the variable is pulling.  I want to echo/print, documentwrite  out what the variable is.  want to see what it is displaying in code?

Comment: Ok...  in jsfiddle I was able to get it to finally work.   Now I put the code into my wordpress template and it just doesn't seem to pull up any of the tables.  it hides the tables but doesn't pull up the tables.  uggghhh...

Comment: Can you update your fiddle with the last modification that you do

Comment: @ShadyNicNack I change the script and html, now all the calculation is working and you don't get duplicated rows

Comment: Awesome.. thanks...  Almost had it the item list  calculation part working at one point but couldn't figure out how to get the total working which is to only display the total of all item cost.  i used an if check statmente then  try removing the table rows like this 

$('table#add_item_here tr#row_id'+index).remove();
                 $('table#add_totals_here tr#rowtot_id'+index).remove();

but yours worked better and its cleaner than mine.

Comment: Noticed in jsfiddle that the code above doesn't have the total cost of all items and the total training.  I can try to work on it by looking at your code.   Ill try to apply it to the wordpress template this weekend.  Keep you posted.

Comment: I added borders to the tables that you can see better the values of each column

Comment: Tried it out this weekend and been working on it...   On fiddle, works like what I wanted.  However, when I apply it to the real site.  it seems that the first part of it having once checked, it puts the item in the list.  then when it is unchecked, it takes it off.  That feature doesn't work in my wordpress template.  Basically you have to check it, then pick the years and then it applies in the list.  And it won't allow us to uncheck it and take it off.

Comment: Ok got that fixed...  Fixed the function on once checked, add it and once unchecked don't add it.  :)   however noticed that the var item = $('#item_chk'+index).parent().text().trim();  is not correct.  It suppose to show the name of the item, which it is in the hidden value of .  in fiddle it shows, but on the website it doesn't show the item name which is in a hidden value of <input type='hidden' name='itemdescr' id='itemdescr".$row->contractid."' value='$item'>

Comment: Ok got that fixed.  I add another variable var itemdescr = $('#itemdescr'+index).val(); within the AddNewItem(index) and then replaced the item_chk with the new variable and that seems to work.  Now just have to create the total hours and cost.

Comment: ok...  I thought i had it working but having issues. I realized that I have 5 different quote forms and using the same variable between them.  so if some one goes to one form and click on an item and marks 3  and then goes to another form and marks the same item, it doesn't mark the number...